# Using %s within a Selenium method

Tags: python, selenium

Right now I have the method below, it works perfectly fine but I want to change part of the self.wait_for_element(....) to instead use %s rather than calling str(counter)

```
> def gather_recent_visited_courses_in_content_switcher(self):      
    hover_courses = self.browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-content flyout-closed')]")
    course_list = []
    counter = 1
    for course in hover_courses:
        self.hover_over(course)
        # Change the below to %s
        self.wait_for_element("//div[contains(@class, 'fly-wrapper recent-content-trigger')][" + str(counter) + "]//div[contains(@class, 'recent-content-info')]", 'Course list not found')
        course_display_name = course.find_element_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'recent-content-info')]").text
        course_list.append(str(course_display_name))
        counter += 1
    return course_list
```

Currently I keep getting errors when replacing it with [%s], like below

```
> self.wait_for_element("//div[contains(@class, 'fly-wrapper recent-content-trigger')][%s]//div[contains(@class, 'recent-content-info')]", 'Course list not found' %(counter))
```

Does anyone have any ideas on how to get this to work properly? So far, I keep getting 'not all arguments converted during string formatting' errors

Comment: Just a reminder. If you find that an answer solves your issue, please click on the green check mark to the left of the answer.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why using `%s` isn't working is because you are setting the placeholder value in the second string argument, and not the first string as you have intended.

With the first argument:

```
"//div[contains(@class, ...)][%s]//div[... 'recent-content-info')]"
```

Python can't find the proper value to replace `%s` with in the first string argument. So, that will raise an error.

As for the second argument:

```
'Course list not found' % (counter)
```

You are passing a value to the string but the string cannot be formatted to use the passed value because the string doesn't have placeholder, `%s`. So, that'll raise an error too.

To fix that, just format the first string argument. It'll look like this:

```
"//div[contains(@class, '...')][%s]//div[..., 'recent-content-info')]" % counter
```

Alternatively, you can use `.format()`. This the new style of string formatting. Using `%s` is considered to be the old style<sup>[1]</sup>.

```
"//div[contains(@class, '...')][{}]//div[..., 'recent-co...')]".format(counter)
```

**NOTE:** Strings have been redacted to make things easier to read.

---

#### References

- [1] - https://pyformat.info/